# Excel: How to get threshold of n% of a set of values?

Tags: excel

Suppose I have an array of values (A1:An).
I would like to perform an operation for those that are in the top k% (say top 5%, but it has to be configurable).

Is there an Excel function that takes as its input my (A1:An) array and the value "k", and returns the threshold that splits my array into (100-k)% under [threshold] and k% above [threshold] ?

For instance, if my dataset is {3, 4, 5, 6, 17, 28, 39, 210, 411, 512} and I called "GET_THRESHOLD(A1:A10; 0.7)" I would expect 39 (or 210).

Comment: Is the input sorted, as in your example?  If Yes then you can just index directly to the array based on k, otherwise if unsorted some combination of LARGE(), k and the number of elements might work.

Comment: It is not (and it is a 2D array). It's more like {{17, 39, 411},{3, 512, 28},{4, 210, 4}} and I want to call GET_THRESHOLD(A1:C3; 0.7)

Comment: Is it an actual array, or a range on a worksheet?

Comment: I think it's called `PERCENTILE()`. I'm not at a computer right now so I can't verify.

Comment: The data spans throughout several cells on the same sheet of my excel document

Answer (score 0):

Let's be honest - Aganju gave the answer in the comments : the function I was looking for is indeed `PERCENTILE`.

The adequate call is `PERCENTILE(A1:C3, 0.7)` -- well, to be a bit more precise and up-to-date, `PERCENTILE.EXC` and `PERCENTILE.INC`.